Uncountable version Helly's theorem
I am trying to solve Exercise 7.4 of Imre Bárány's lecture note of Discrete mathematics.
"Prove that Helly's theorem when family is not countable and every set in the family is compact"
I used a completeness of Euclidean space, $\mathbb{R}^d$, an intersection of all sets in the family would be a subset of finite intersection of the sets.
$$\cap_{C \in \mathcal{F}} C \subset \cap_{C \in \mathcal{D}} C$$
where, $\mathcal{D} \subset \mathcal{F}, |\mathcal{D}|=N <\infty$.
If I define a sequence $\{z_i\}_{i=1}$ as,
$$\{z_i\}_{i=1} := \{z_i | z_i \in \left( \cap_{C \in \mathcal{D}} C \right) \cap \left( 
 \cap_{C \notin \mathcal{D}, C\in \mathcal{F}}^i C\right)\}$$
then, by the finite version of Helly's theorem $\exists z_i \, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}_{+}$ and the sequence is a Cauchy sequence. There exists an unique convergent point $z$.
$z \in \left( \cap_{C \in \mathcal{D}} C \right) \cap \left( 
 \cap_{C \notin \mathcal{D}, C\in \mathcal{F}}^i C\right) \, \forall i$, and $\cap_{C \in \mathcal{F}} C $ be a subset of the intersection.
My question: I stuck in here. Do I guarantee the point $z$ is exists in $\cap_{C \in \mathcal{F}} C $? The proof would be finished if the claim is hold true.

To prove Helly's theorem for a non-countable family of compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$, use the compactness of these sets and the completeness of Euclidean space. The theorem states that if in every finite subcollection of a family of convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$, the intersection is non-empty, then the intersection of the entire family is also non-empty.
